# Cannot deploy solution with feature receiver

Tags: sharepoint-server, deployment, feature-receiver

I have a weird problem. I have a Sharepoint 2013 solution with two features, one of which has a feature receiver with some code in it. If I deploy this solution either through SPSD or Visual Studio 2013, I get an error

```
Error occured in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to load receiver assembly '...' for feature '...'
```

I can only deploy my solution if I delete the feature receiver, I don't even need to have any code other than that which Visual Studio generates in the receiver for it to fail. The deployment target of my solution is GAC, as I read somewhere else that feature receivers cannot be deployed to WebApps.

Can anybody help me here?

Comment: Do you have additional assembly(-ies) in wsp-package? If so, are they all deployed to GAC?

Comment: Yes, an external class library. Do you think this is causing problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution to the problem was to change assembly version from 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.1 and build the SharePoint project. After that I deleted feature receiver and added feature receiver again so that feature manifest XML file gets updated with correct version of feature receiver assembly.

More details on http://slavensemper.blogspot.hr/2015/08/failed-to-load-receiver-assembly.html.

Comment: this worked. strange solution but I am glad that the problem is gone nonetheless. thank you sir!